# APN Switch for sprint devices

Tags: internet, apn, cdma

I have used APNDroid on many of my phones in the past. I have recently started using some sprint devices and noticed that this APN toggle widget will not disable the network connection on these devices. I don't know if it is something because of the different network type, or some other reason. Can anyone point me to another application that you've had luck using to turn off the data connection on sprint phone?

Comment: For anyone else who finds this: Tasker has an action that will shut off data on CDMA devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APNDroid doesn't work on CDMA phones.  This appears to be the case with most such apps.  [Internet Scheduler](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jmpdroids.internetscheduler.free) and [GreenPower](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.gpo.greenpower) claim to work on them if you have Gingerbread, though.

There are some other solutions you can try in [this Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/tasker/browse_thread/thread/bc6b40131ed09252).